# shinyapps.IO custom URL for content selected by selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I would like to have a custom URL generated in shinyapps.IO (or willing to upgrade to appropriate Enterprise tools) based on value selected by `selectInput()`. In the example below, if I publish to shinyapps.IO, the URL will be https://myDomain.shinyapps.io/myAppName/.

I would like 5 unique URLs, based on the user-selected option from selectInput().

- https://myDomain.shinyapps.io/myAppName/Option1
- https://myDomain.shinyapps.io/myAppName/Option2
- https://myDomain.shinyapps.io/myAppName/Option3
- https://myDomain.shinyapps.io/myAppName/Option4
- https://myDomain.shinyapps.io/myAppName/Option5

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(tidyverse)

#################### UI   ###################
ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  ###### Header ####
  
  header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
    title = NULL,
    titleWidth = '250',
    disable = FALSE,
    enable_rightsidebar = FALSE,
    .list = NULL,
    left_menu = tagList(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "options",
        label = "Select an option",
        choices = c('Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3', 'Option4', 'Option5'))
    ) #end left_menu
  ), #close Header
  
  
  ###### Sidebar ####
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  
  footer = dashboardFooter(NULL),
  ###### Body ####
  body = dashboardBody(
    uiOutput('optionSelected')
  ) #close dashboardBody
) # closes Dashboard Page Plus

#################### SERVER   #################### 
server = function(input, output, session) { 
 
  output$optionSelected <- renderUI({
    input$options
  }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have read about 'Vanity URLs' at https://community.rstudio.com/t/vanity-urls-with-connect-via-deployapp/18927/4, but this does not quite seem like the solution that I am seeking.

Thank for any advice.

Comment: I think you are looking for bookmarking: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/enableBookmarking.html.

Comment: [Here](https://deanattali.com/blog/advanced-shiny-tips/#url-inputs) you can find another approach using `session$clientData$url_search`.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thank you for sharing this resource!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like i mentioned in the comment, i think you are looking for bookmarking, see `?shiny::enableBookmarking()`.

For bookmarking you have to make three modifications to your code. Make

1. the ui code a function

   ```
   ui <- function(request){...}
   ```
2. include a bookmark trigger/button in your ui

   ```
   bookmarkButton()
   ```
3. Enable bookmarking before you launch the app.

   ```
   enableBookmarking("url")
   ```

**Minimal reproducible example would be:**

```
ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    selectInput("options", "opt", choices = c('Option1', 'Option2')),
    bookmarkButton()
  )
}
server <- function(input, output, session) { }
enableBookmarking("url")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Automating the generation of urls**

```
port_nr <- 3033
input_id <- "select_opt"
choices <- c('Option1', 'Option2')
paste0("http://127.0.0.1:", port_nr, "/?_inputs_&", input_id, "=", 
   URLencode(choices, reserved = TRUE))
```

**Your example would read:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- function(request) {
    dashboardPagePlus(
    ###### Header ####
    
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      title = NULL,
      titleWidth = '250',
      disable = FALSE,
      enable_rightsidebar = FALSE,
      .list = NULL,
      left_menu = tagList(
        selectInput(
          inputId = "options",
          label = "Select an option",
          choices = c('Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3', 'Option4', 'Option5'))
      ) #end left_menu
    ), #close Header
    
    
    ###### Sidebar ####
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
    
    footer = dashboardFooter(NULL),
    ###### Body ####
    body = dashboardBody(
      uiOutput('optionSelected'),
      bookmarkButton()
    ) #close dashboardBody
  ) # closes Dashboard Page Plus
}
#################### SERVER   #################### 
server = function(input, output, session) { 
  
  output$optionSelected <- renderUI({
    input$options
  }
  )
}
enableBookmarking("url")
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something a bit more automated, but I appreciate your efforts and can use this idea as a workaround. Thanks again for your time and talent!

Comment: understood! See my edit, section 'Automating the generation of urls'.